# Mysqlnd native driver not working even though loaded

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlnd

The output of `php -i | grep mysqlnd` is:

> Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id:
>   40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4
>   Client API library version
>   => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4
>   mysqlnd mysqlnd => enabled
>   Version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d
>   Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
>   mysqlnd statistics => Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev -
>   20120503 - $Id: 40933630edef551dfaca71298a83fad8d03d62d4

[image]

Which suggests it's loaded `mysqlnd => enabled` however all the database values are still coming out as strings, not converted to native PHP types:

```
$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'my_database');

// Settings contains one tinyint field 'enabled'
$result = mysqli_query($connection, 'select * from settings');

var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

**Result**

```
array (size=1)
    'enabled' => string '1' (length=1)
```

**Expected**

```
array (size=1)
   'enabled' => int 1
```

Am I missing some config/any suggestions?

Comment: So show us piece of code and the error message you have please :-)

Comment: @KimAlexander I've added some code. Not really much to it. The mysqlnd   driver should automatically convert to PHP data types where possible, but it's not. They're still coming out as strings even though according to PHP mysqlnd is loaded and enabled.

Comment: you will always get strings, I think that the reason is native sql engine, when it return data, there is no additional information about every column, just data. so it is always strings , either for datestamp. Did you see any other information over internet? if you saw any example if php code that shows that mysqli return INT or DATE formal - show me please :-)

Comment: @KimAlexander please read about what the mysqlnd driver is for. It's exactly for that reason. It's tightly coupled to the PHP so it can detect mysql data types and convert to PHP types.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that mysqlnd is only available when your using PDO.

I've changed my code to use PDO and also ensured that emulated prepares is off (otherwise it still will return strings). Now it converts to PHP data types! :-)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_database', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $pdo->query('select * from settings');

var_dump($result->fetch());
```

**Result**

```
array (size=1)
  'enabled' => int 1
```